# What the correct way to print exception in python?

Tags: python, exception, format

There are at least 5 ways to print exception information in python.

```
except Exception as e:
     print(e)
     print(str(e))
     print(e.what())
     print('{}'.format(e))
     print(pformat(e))
```

What is the correct way and what is the pythonic one?

Comment: pythonic way is `raise` exception. "Errors should never pass silently." All the ways you described is correct.

Comment: @JonhyBeebop OP is asking about how to *print* an exception, not how to raise one.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Yes, you right, but exceptions will be printed to stderr. I think this is the most correct way.

Comment: @JonhyBeebop only if it is not handled (which halts the program). The presence of `except` suggests that OP wants to print the error message *without* halting.

Comment: You can use [https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) module `logging.error(e)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use traceback after catching your exception:

```
import traceback
traceback.print_exc()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
except Exception as e:
     print(e)
```

use below link for more examples
https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/error-handling/exception-handling-in-python